# Wordpress: move media folder

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, directory, move

I want to move a folder (/uploads/2010) to another server, but I want the main site to have access to files from folder moved.

For example, if now I have a picture url:
2010/pic.jpg

Full url: http://www.domanin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/pic.jpg

the new url will be:
http://www.domanin-2.com/uploads/2010/pic.jpg

Is there any solution for my problem?

Apologize for my English!

Comment: yep, try mod_rewrite - can rewrite 404s on your new server to try on your old.

Comment: How can I do this for several folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point `www.domanin-2.com` to another server. You're able to do this by editing DNS  records for `domanin-2.com`. In this case you'll be able to read files, but if you want to write files there, you'd have to change Wordpress's source code, to allow the communication between 2 servers (e.g via [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)).

Comment: Not work, but thanks for your answer.
Maybe someone has another idea ... The folder called 2010 containing hundreds of files

Comment: @user2151960 you should move the folder to another server, too

Comment: Thank you! I added .htaccess the following line: `Redirect 301 /wp-content/uploads/2010/ http://www.domanin2/uploads/2010/` Now it works

Answer (score 0):

I honestly haven't dived deep into this solution, as I should jump into the adventure soon; the way CDNs are setup you can separate the web server from static files onto a different server.

This is the area I am unfamiliar with, but probably could find documentation, depending on the servers configuration. You would be connecting the two. At this point, the prereqs would be Sysop level. I may have to write documentation on this as my server configuration is a bit out of the ordinary.